# Почему импортируя модуль sys символ "!" переходит на след. строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Код:

```
import sys

name = sys.stdin.readline()
print('Hi', name + '!')
```

Результат (например):

Hi James
!

А мне нужно:
Hi James!

Причём нужно именно с sys, т.к. сейчас изучаю его. Скажите почему восклицательный знак переходит на след. строку, вместо того чтобы оставться на той же. Надеюсь вы поняли, сори я чайник xD.

Comment: потому что readline() возвращает строку вместе с переводом каретки, который у нее в конце. удалите его, например с помощью rstrip()

Comment: благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать например так, отредактируйте аргументы rstrip() под свои нужды.

```
import sys

name = sys.stdin.readline()
print('Hi', str(name).rstrip('\n') + '!')
```

Comment: Спасибо, а обязательно использовать str() или можно просто name.rstrip('\n')(просто и так работает)?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно. Указал, так как не был уверен какой тип данных возвращает sys.stdin()

Comment: спасибо большое